# Не запускается гостевая ОС в VirtualBox: Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: virtualbox, драйвер, kernel

Стоит Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia, ядро 5.4.0-37-generic на ноутбуке, в BIOS которого включен UEFI и отключен Secure Boot.
При запуске гостевой операционной системы получаю ошибку, описанную ниже. Перепробовал много разных вариантов которые предлагаю в интернете: откат на ядро 5.0, которое было установлено изначально с Linux, установка / переустановка разных пакетов, модулей - но ничего не помогает.

**Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)**

> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
> correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the
> kernel module by executing
>
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
>
> as root.
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign
> the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before
> you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for
> more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
> support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

при команде
modprobe vboxdrv
получаю
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic

$ apt install vboxdrv

Чтение списков пакетов…
Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей
Чтение информации о состоянии…
Готово
E: Невозможно найти пакет vboxdrv

и так для всех пакетов: vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci

Подскажите, что делать чтобы запустить гостевую ОС?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, оставляю этот пост для кого-то, у кого будет подобная проблема.
Для того, чтобы избавиться от ошибки необходимо:
откатиться на одну из версий ядра, напротив которой стоит "+"

5.4 -

5.3 +

5.0 -

4.18 +

4.15 +

Алгоритм такой: старт - менеджер обновлений - вид - ядра линукс. Выбрать одно из списка выше, где стоит + и установить его. Ребутнуться, нажимая ESC / Shift выбрать нужную версию ядра.
Для ноутбуков, у которых стоит эмулятор BIOS, "UEFI" - нужно во время загрузки BIOS вместо SHIFT нажимать ESC.